# Angularjs - dynamically set $scope variable

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am new to angular and am trying to do something pretty simple in vanilla javascript but am unable to find out how to do it properly in angular!

I want to set up a general function to clear an input text field:

I have this html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="css" ng-focus="clearInput('css')"/>
```

(got the ng-focus thing here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/A5Lyx8m3S4M
 it works well!)

and this function in my controller

```
$scope.clearInput = function (val) {
 $scope.val  = "";
};
```

Clearly this would work if I would use $scope.css, but I want to be able use the function for other input fields as well. There's got to be a nice angular way of doing this!!

Thanks!

## Heading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier just to clear it using `"css=''"`.

For example, the following clears the input each time you click on it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="css" ng-click="css=''"></input>
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple. Thanks Andy! Another light bulb just lit up!